# Bloc State not reload or updating widget ui when i was emit a list

Tags: flutter, list, state, reload, bloc

i try to change listSelctedTest with add/remove function in bloc, but my ui widget not reload/update after emit a listSelectedTest. but, if using ctr+s/hot reload it will change to new value and reload my ui widget.old value = 2 and new value = 2 & 4.

Bloc

```
void _onChangeTest(OnPriceChangeTest event, var emit) {
final state = this.state;
if (state is PriceChangeTest) {
  try {
    List<String> listSelectedTest = state.copyWith().listSelectedTest ?? [];
    printlog("price change test-1", "$listSelectedTest");
    if (event.selected) {
      listSelectedTest.remove(event.value);
    } else {
      listSelectedTest.add(event.value);
    }
    printlog("price change test-2", listSelectedTest.toString());
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        listSelectedTest: listSelectedTest,
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    printlog("price change test", e.toString());
  }
}
```

> i was try to using spread operator (...) and List.from(), but nothing has change

Comment: Please [don't post your code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use code blocks.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot it, thanks for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```dart
List<String> listSelectedTest = state.copyWith().listSelectedTest ?? [];
```

You're not copying the list, but rather the list is still referring to the same list as the one currently in the state. Replace `state.copyWith().listSelectedTest` with `[...state.listSelectedTest]` so that you make sure that the current state won't be affected by the modification done in the next lines with the `remove` or `add` method. This will make the states before and after you call `emit` are actually different so that the widget will rebuild based on the changes.